# What is needed to automatically run Cron tasks created with Gnome Schedule?

Tags: cron, gnome-schedule

I used [Gnome Schedule](http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/) to create the following test task. The task runs fine manually but is not being run every hour automatically as defined.

What is required for this task to run automatically?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [specify](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GNOME_Schedule/) what your default output display is. 
*(Sorry, the above reference is in German. I could not find anything else.)*

**A)** In the cmd field, introduce: 
 either  
     `DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/notify-send test`  
or  
     `export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/notify-send test` 
and report on result in a comment below if needed.

**B)** You may also try running your GUI cmd `notify-send` as an "X application". You can select that out of the unfolding menu, in the field directly below yr cmd field.

**WHY** it is so: 
"Gnome Schedule" is based in part on `crontab`, but `crontab` doesn't know about yr general user's environment variables. To get more information on that, do (in terminal):

```
$ man 5 crontab
```

As a result you need to specify:

- what yr `stdout` (i.e. yr standard display) is within the cron-job itself.
- the path prefix of yr cmds, whenever said cmd-executables are not found in `/usr/bin/`. Concretely for `notify-send`, it is in  principle superfluous to prefix its full path. Do so anyway for *all* cmds as a healthy habit...

HTH.